# Understanding CSS selectors. Hover to show information from another div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a setup for displaying information as the user hovers over a specific element. When the specific element is hovered over, the information will appear in an adjacent div depending on which div the user hovers over. Here's the HTML...

```css
#emp-node:hover+#emp-details {
  opacity: 1;
}

.node-details {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="half interactions">
  <div id="nodes">
    <div id="emp-node" class="node">EMPATHY</div>
    <div id="def-node" class="node">DEFINE</div>
    <div id="id-node" class="node">IDEATE</div>
    <div id="por-node" class="node">PROTOTYPE</div>
    <div id="test-node" class="node">TESTING</div>
  </div>
  <div id="node-text">
    <div id="emp-details" class="node-details">1</div>
    <div id="def-details" class="node-details">2</div>
    <div id="id-details" class="node-details">3</div>
    <div id="por-details" class="node-details">4</div>
    <div id="test-details" class="node-details">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The node-details are set to an opacity of 0. When I hover over emp-node I would like emp-details to show, and the same pattern for the other divs. Here's the CSS...

```
#emp-node:hover + #emp-details { opacity: 1; }
```

I believe my issue is with the selector. I know that I need to use one but I've tried them all to no avail. Can some help me figure out how to get this to work properly? Do I need to restructure my HTML or is there a solution?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: It would work if elements were siblings.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a bit of javascript/jquery for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind CSS can take you just part of the way, for example there is no parent selectors in CSS yet, you can not  *walk back*. For stuff like that there is JS.

So for you its restructure HTML, for example you simply make them siblings, to be on same level at least:

```css
#emp-node:hover~#emp-details {
  opacity: 1;
}

#def-node:hover~#def-details {
  opacity: 1;
}
#id-node:hover~#id-details {
  opacity: 1;
}
#test-node:hover~#test-details {
  opacity: 1;
}

.node-details {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="half interactions">
  <div id="nodes">
    <div id="emp-node" class="node">EMPATHY</div>
    <div id="def-node" class="node">DEFINE</div>
    <div id="id-node" class="node">IDEATE</div>
    <div id="por-node" class="node">PROTOTYPE</div>
    <div id="test-node" class="node">TESTING</div>
    <div id="emp-details" class="node-details">1</div>
    <div id="def-details" class="node-details">2</div>
    <div id="id-details" class="node-details">3</div>
    <div id="por-details" class="node-details">4</div>
    <div id="test-details" class="node-details">5</div>
</div>
```

Or javascript:

```
 document.querySelectorAll("#nodes > .node").forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    let id = this.id.split("-")
    //get ids
    document.querySelectorAll("#node-text > .node-details").forEach(details => {
      details.style.opacity = 0;
    });
    //on every hover set all to opacity 0
    document.querySelector("#node-text > div[id^='" + id[0] + "']").style.opacity = 1;
  });
  //set the one that id bigins with id of hover element opacity 1
});
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#nodes > .node").forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
    let id = this.id.split("-")
    document.querySelectorAll("#node-text > .node-details").forEach(details => {
      details.style.opacity = 0;
    });
    document.querySelector("#node-text > div[id^='" + id[0] + "']").style.opacity = 1;
  });
});
```

```css
.node-details {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="half interactions">
  <div id="nodes">
    <div id="emp-node" class="node">EMPATHY</div>
    <div id="def-node" class="node">DEFINE</div>
    <div id="id-node" class="node">IDEATE</div>
    <div id="por-node" class="node">PROTOTYPE</div>
    <div id="test-node" class="node">TESTING</div>
  </div>
  <div id="node-text">
    <div id="emp-details" class="node-details">1</div>
    <div id="def-details" class="node-details">2</div>
    <div id="id-details" class="node-details">3</div>
    <div id="por-details" class="node-details">4</div>
    <div id="test-details" class="node-details">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Useful topic:
[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your needs by removing the 2 div wrappers id nodes and node-text as the below :

Html`

```
<div class="half interactions">
 <div id="emp-node"classs="node">EMPATHY</div>
 <div id="def-node" class="node">DEFINE</div>
 <div id="id-node" class="node">IDEATE</div>
 <div id="por-node" class="node">PROTOTYPE</div>
 <div id="test-node" class="node">TESTING</div>

 <div id="emp-details" class="node-details">1</div>
 <div id="def-details" class="node-details">2</div>
 <div id="id-details" class="node-details">3</div>
 <div id="por-details" class="node-details">4</div>
 <div id="test-details" class="node-details">5</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
#emp-node:hover ~ #emp-details {
 opacity: 1;
}

.node-details {
   opacity: 0;
 }
```

Codepen https://codepen.io/ahamdan/pen/gOMaeNv